# How to make contact form 7 to redirect after submission to url?(dont work)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

how to make contact form 7 to redirect to a specific page after submission ?
i have tried everything and nothing seems to work.
See the code that i used:

```
<?php if ( is_page('page-id-17135')) { ?>

<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location = 'http://****.com/bg/vaprosi/';
    }, false );
</script>

<?php } else if ( is_page('page-id-17160')) { ?>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
           location = 'http://****.com/bg/porachka/';
        }, false );
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

so it doesnt seem to work.
Any idea what i did wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Just Put following code to Additional Settings of contact form 7**

on_sent_ok: "location='add your redirect url here'"

Comment: it is depreciated for the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

From [Contact Form 7's site](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) the following script works:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
```